# C++ Windows Form Application Mysql Connection

Tags: c++, mysql, winapi

I can't seem to figure out how to connect to mysql in my windows form application. I've installed all the proper libraries and have included them, thats not the issue. The issue is I can't find a tutorial on connecting to mysql. I've found some one console applications, tried them, but yet for some reason they do not work. I just need to be sent into the right direction, thanks.

Comment: What library are you using for MySQL?

Comment: I'm using the MySQL Connector C++ 1.0.5 off of the mysql website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what library you're using, but I recommend [MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/). It's simple, has a great manual and lot of examples.